# schedule task through IPC connection can not be run correctly

Tags: ipc

Here is a windows 7 ultimate, which is logged on by a normal user, and this user is a member of administrators group, then I use another computer which is in the same LAN to build an IPC connection with that windows 7, I connect as administrator, and then I use schtasks build a schedule task, which is very simple, just executing a batch file, but I have no idea why this schedule task can not be run?

Below is the command I use to connect with the windows 7 and create schedule task:

```
net use \\10.10.10.148 "password" /user:administrator
copy simple.bat \\10.10.10.148\c$
schtasks /create /s 10.10.10.148 /u administrator /p password /tn test /sc once /st 08:00 /tr C:\simple.bat /ru administrator /f
```

Here is the content of that simple.bat:

```
rd C:\windows\temp\ipc_test
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out this myself, the reason why schedule task can't be run is the current user's privilege is lower than the schedule task's privilege